# What are potential security vulnerabilities of a multi-tenant Azure AD App Registration

Tags: azure-active-directory

The cloud solution I am working with requires a multi-tenant app registration to be created and used for service-to-service authentication in a SaaS like pattern.  The security team expressed concerns that a multi-tenant identity could be assign resources by another tenant (or external entity) without the security team's visibility or control.  Assuming the App Registration is only used to configure the solution and its not used in the organization for any other purpose and it's fully protected in Azure Key Vault and not shared with any external entity, is this a legitimate concern?  Could there be a way, just because it's a multi-tenant App Registration for it to be discovered and used in a harmful fashion?

Comment: If the client secret of this multi-tenant app registration is not leaked to any other external tenants, they will not be able to access your tenant's information. Is this something you worry about?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use key vault to store the client secrets properly malicious entities won't have access to the tenant.  In fact, an even better mechanism will be to use a [certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) in place of a secret.

Comment: Let me ask you this...  The security team thinks an external tenant can use that app registration in malicious ways, perhaps to use the multi-tenant app registration to create a resource in the external tenant and empower that resource to do something harmful or give that resource unregulated and invisible access to the authoring tenant.  Is any of that a valid concern? Assuming the app password (or certificate) hasn't be compromised, what sorts of evil could another tenant do with a multi-tenant app registration?

Answer (score 0):

See new vulnerability in Jun 2023

https://www.descope.com/blog/post/noauth

Remediation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-off-email-claim-authorization